# Regression i Maple - finding the best possible curve

Tags: plot, maple

Given some data points plotted in a graph by:

```
plot(<<a>|<b>>,style=point);
```

How do I do regression through the points? That is finding the best possible curve, straight line etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the help-pages for the [CurveFitting](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=CurveFitting) package, or those of [Statistics,Regression](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics/Regression). (Note that the latter of those should appear by entering `regression` in the Maple 16 Help browser's search box.)

```
a:=<1,2,3,4,5>:
b:=<2,5,10,17,26>:

P1:=plot(<a|b>,style=point,color=red):

C1:=Statistics:-Fit(s+t*x,a,b,x);

C2:=Statistics:-Fit(s+t*x+u*x^2,a,b,x);

plots:-display( 
            P1,
            plot(C1, x=min(a)..max(a), color=green),
            plot(C2, x=min(a)..max(a), color=blue)
              );
```